# Converting date isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a table with columns:

```
 ID | FirstName | LastName | DOB
```

I'm then populating these columns with data from 2 different tables

```
INSERT INTO ClientData( 
FirstName,
LastName, 
DOB) SELECT FirstName,
            LastName,
            BirthDate 
      FROM Table1
      LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.ID
```

In Table2 the dates of birth are in the format:

```
 1990-01-01
```

But i would like it in the format:

```
01-Jan-1990
```

I've used an Update statement before the insert statement

```
UPDATE ClientData
SET DOB = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DOB, 106)
```

However it does not come out in this format in the final table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: What is the type of "BirthDate" field in table2?

Comment: `exec sp_columns ClientData` is `DOB` a string by any chance?

Comment: Just a follow up: please indicate the data type of column `BirthDate`. Why do you care what the format is? SQL isn't a reporting/formatting tool. Regardless of what you see, if it's a date data type, its stored properly

Comment: What the above comments are hinting at is: if your column data type is still set to `DATE` you'd still end up with that format. That's just how they are stored. If you *REALLY* want the specific format, consider using `VARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, `CHAR`, ... Normally, date formatting is something done on either the front end of your application or during your select. I wouldn't advise to store your dates as string types in your database because you'd lose some functionality that comes with them.

Comment: And additionally: **NEVER** store a date as string and **NEVER NEVER** store it as string with cultlure depending format and **NEVER NEVER NEVER** store it with language depending elements ('Jan' in your case)! Do this only in case of blooming masochism...

Answer (score 0):

try FORMAT instead of CONVERT

```
FORMAT (value, format [, culture ] )
```

Example

```
FORMAT ( BirthDate, 'your pattern', 'en-US' )
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Shnugo mentioned in comment. Your query is fine, just change your schema and never store date as string. always use `DateTime` DataType for both tables `table1` and `table2` and simply convert DataTime in the client side, UI application etc.

Answer (score 0):

first of all CAST that column to datetime then convert it to varchar:

```
       UPDATE ClientData
       SET DOB = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), cast(DOB as datetime), 106)
```